# Scrollbar in Modal box

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9r786Lnv/1)

Instead of making scrollbar to whole modal-dialog how can I make it to only modal body. I have tried few methods like

```
.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial;
}
.modal-body{
    height: 50%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

but it didn't work in my case.

Comment: Take a look at my modal: http://jsfiddle.net/1g76ujxf/

Comment: Yeah It's cool but what is wrong with my modal box? It is not even clicking on close(data-dismiss) is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add :

```
.modal-body{
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-dialog {
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

The modal overlay (z-index:1050) is above the modal content and prevent the scroll. And you have to fix the height too.

Comment: you are welcome. Upvote if you want to help my reputation :)